# How many times has the US defaulted on its debt?

Tags: united-states, debt

I have heard that it would be an [unprecedented occurrence](http://theobamacrat.com/2013/10/08/full-transcript-video-president-obama-delivers-a-statement-on-the-government-shutdown-and-takes-questions/), and that it has never happened.

> If Congress refuses to raise what’s called the debt ceiling, America would not be able to meet all of our financial obligations for the first time in 225 years.

**How many times (and when, if any) has the US defaulted on its debt?**

Comment: Depends on how you define default.  Was the gold standard end in 1933 a default?  Some at the time thought so.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 times that I know of where the US may have defaulted on it's debt.

---

There was a time during the war of 1812 where soldiers were not getting paid

> Once, the young nation had a dramatic excuse: The Treasury was empty,
>   the White House and Capitol were charred ruins, even the troops
>   fighting the War of 1812 weren't getting paid.

at least not immediately

> the Treasury was unable to move enough precious metal to service its
>   debt, and missed interest payments on bonds. Boston bondholders,
>   according to Wayne State College history professor Don Hickey, were
>   paid off in short-term interest-bearing treasury notes or more bonds.

---

There was another time in 1979 where technical difficulties presumably resulted in some bills not getting paid on time.

> A second time, in 1979, was a back-office glitch that ended up costing
>   taxpayers billions of dollars. The Treasury Department blamed the
>   mishap on a crush of paperwork partly caused by lawmakers who — this
>   will sound familiar — bickered too long before raising the nation's
>   debt limit.

which, also was payed off

> This default was temporary. Treasury did pay these T-bills after a
>   short delay. But it balked at paying additional interest to cover the
>   period of delay. According to Zivney and Marcus, it required both
>   legal arm twisting and new legislation before Treasury made all
>   investors whole for that additional interest.

---

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/10/14/us-debt-defaults_n_4097380.html
http://dailycaller.com/2013/10/16/government-default-its-already-happened-twice/
http://dmarron.com/tag/debt-limit/